# "Unselect All" features when importing a site template to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: solution-package, site-template, visual-studio-2012, import

In Visual Studio 2012 I'm importing a WSP of a site template using the "SharePoint Customization Wizard."  The list of features displays with all items selected.  I only want to import a couple features so find I must scroll thru the entire list unchecking each feature (mostly fields and content types).  Is there anyway of "unselecting all" at the start?

Comment: Just realized the solution - use shift and mouse click to select desired block of features in the list, then space-bar to uncheck.

Comment: You can also add them all and then carefully remove all the unnecessary stuff from your project in solution explorer. :)